# Geotools with maven: java.lang.noclassdeffounderror while starting app's jar

Tags: java, geotools, maven

In my Idea everything works fine but when I try to start my jar which was built by maven there are some errors:

1 - Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

2 - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/FeatureSource

3 - Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.data.FeatureSource

It looks like it can't find FeatureSource class.

I experimented with java code and found out that it can't find and other GeoTools classes. This error becomes when I try to create object of any GeoTool's class. So I can get the same error for FeatureSource or StyleFactory or MapContent.

My classpath is ok and all dependencies are also ok. Maven put all my dependencies (and GeoTools jars and their subdependecies) to target\lib directory and other not GeoTools libs (like mysql-connector-java) work fine.

Jar stats fine if I remove calling to GeoTools classes in the code. I don't print my java code because issue isn't in java code but in some SDK or maven (pom) settings.

Here is my dependencies:

[image]

I start jar by ***"java -jar siveria.avl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"*** in cmd. My lib dir is in ${project.build.directory} so it has project_name\target\lib\ path and it's not in project_name\target\classes\ dir in my classes dir there are only my main project's package dir and dirs from resources dir.

Here is my Project's target directory structure:

[image]

Here is my Project's src directory structure:

[image]

Here is my POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>AVL</groupId>
<artifactId>siveria.avl</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>siveria.avl</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <geotools.version>2.7-M2</geotools.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
          <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
          <name>Java.net repository</name>
          <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
        <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
        <version>8.40.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
        <version>19-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
        <version>19-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>fxgraphics2d</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
        <version>19-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
        <version>${java.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jfxrt.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <index>true</index>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>AVL.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                        ${project.build.directory}/lib
                    </outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
  <resources>
      <resource>
          <directory>src/main/java/AVL/resources</directory>
          <includes>
              <include>**/*.fxml</include>
              <include>**/*.css</include>
              <include>**/*.jpg</include>
              <include>**/*.png</include>
              <include>**/*.ico</include>
              <include>**/*.cpg</include>
              <include>**/*.dbf</include>
              <include>**/*.prj</include>
              <include>**/*.qix</include>
              <include>**/*.ico</include>
              <include>**/*.shp</include>
              <include>**/*.shx</include>
              <include>**/*.sld</include>
          </includes>
      </resource>

  </resources>
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
Exception in Application start method 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Lau
ncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication 
(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1 
    (LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155 
    (LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/data/FeatureSource
    at AVL.controllers.MapController.initialize(MapController.java:32)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at AVL.Main.start(Main.java:29)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
    (LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175 
    (PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173 
    (PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174 
    (PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run 
    (InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148 
    (WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    org.geotools.data.FeatureSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
    Exception running application AVL.Main
```

Comment: how are you running the jar? it looks like you don't have the dependencies on your class path

Comment: @Ian Turton

I start jar by "java -jar siveria.avl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" in cmd.

My lib dir is in ${project.build.directory} so it has 
project_name\target\lib\ path 
and it's not in 
project_name\target\classes\ dir

in my classes dir there are only my main project's package dir and dirs from resources dir.

I've added a Project's structure image to description.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question in response to requests for clarification. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: Dear @Vince, sorry but I didn't understand your comment... What should I add to the main topic description? I've added the screens of the project's structure... as I understand it's good addon for describing the issue which answers on Ian's question.

Comment: The **most** important information, with respect to your problem, only exists as a comment. The `java` invocation line should be prominent in your question, not hidden in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a java program run you need to include all of its dependencies on the classpath so that the JVM can find them or include them in the jar itself so that it is truly portable.

In the first case, this can be achieved by adding your maven repository to the command line:

```
java -jar -cp .:~/.m2/repository/ siveria.avl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

or for the second (and probably better) case you need to create an "uber" or "fat" jar. This combines all the needed jars into one big one that you can execute with no classpath. This is accomplished using the [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) since this handles the `services/spi` metadata files that GeoTools uses to handle datastore lookups.

You need to include [something](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) like:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
              <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
              <target>1.8</target>
              <source>1.8</source>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <!-- This bit sets the main class for the executable jar as you otherwise -->
                          <!-- would with the assembly plugin                                       -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                              <manifestEntries>
                                  <Main-Class>org.geotools.demo.Quickstart</Main-Class>
                              </manifestEntries>
                          </transformer>
                          <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

A final option is to use Maven to [execute](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) the program using its knowledge of your dependencies. By including something like and then using `mvn exec:java`:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
               <mainClass>org.geotools.tutorial.quickstart.Quickstart</mainClass>
               <commandlineArgs>../../data/ne_10m_admin_0_countries.shp</commandlineArgs>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Dear @Ian Turton, thank you very much for your reply! It was very useful! 
I used the second option with the shade plugin. My jar has started but everything that considers to GeoTools is not working. I have to notice that during the build there was error messages about all GTs jars: [WARNING] The POM for org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:sources:19-20180108.192838-162 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Could not get sources for org.geotools:gt-shapefile:jar:19-SNAPSHOT:compile. They were created in the uber-jar but with 0 size. Do you have any ideas why it can't find them?

Comment: also I want to notice that Idea underlined red the org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:<unknown> label in maven plugin dialog section, wich means that there is some kind of error with this plugin but I can't understand what is it. Or it should be so and the underline is ok?

Comment: I've updated the answer with the shade code from the tutorial which I have just tested locally and found to be working. - Are you sure you added it in the correct place, does `mvn package` run with out error?

Comment: SOLVED! After your update it has found the libs and was built correctyly. App started and everything works fine! Thank you very much! I very appreciate your help.